# Parshiot Devarim referring to mashiach

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, vilna-gaon, deuteronomy

Where does the vilna gaon say that the parshiot of devarim are a remez to the last generations of before mashiach?

Comment: Where did you see it?

Comment: I heard it.  Hence my question

Comment: I too am in search of the source

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30691/27180

Comment: https://www.torchweb.org/torah_detail.php?id=114 , https://torah.org/torah-portion/perceptions-5759-haazinu/?printversion=1